# Postgres: Check function input array for null or empty or containing null

Tags: postgresql

I am looking to validate argument input to check, for example, that the _product_ids::BIGINT[] is not null, or does not contain null (or optionally, does not contain only null), or is not empty.

Here is what I have:

```
IF (
  _product_ids IS NULL -- Is null
  OR -1 = ANY(_product_ids) IS NULL -- Contains null
  OR COALESCE(ARRAY_LENGTH(_product_ids, 1) < 1, TRUE) -- Is empty
) THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'INPUT IS INVALID';
END IF;
```

I would like to tweak 'Contains null' so that it'll return true only if there is only nulls. Additionally, I would like to know if there is a way to check for null and empty array at the same time.

PostgresSQL 9.6 is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression may look like this:

```
_product_ids is null -- is null
or cardinality(_product_ids) = 0 -- is empty
or (select bool_and(e is null) from unnest(_product_ids) e) -- contains only nulls
```

Comment: Should I be concerned about performance of unnest if the size of the array is expected to be below <= 16?

Comment: Surely the expression is more expensive than a simple compare with `any()` but I don't think the difference if very significant.